# Pass Gamepad data to windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, gamepad

I am creating a Gamepad for windows on the .NET framework using C#, and I am stuck, how do I pass my button event data and the axis data to windows? So for example, if `button 1` is pressed it will pass that `1` is triggered and so forth.

I have googled it and came across couple of msdn guides but none of them really identify how to do it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757112.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on the hardware you're using. But this page might give you some help:-

[http://youhacklife.com/featured/gamepad-game-controller-in-csharp](http://slimdx.org/index.php)

And the full SlimDX Direct X library is at:-

http://slimdx.org/index.php

Comment: Do you know of a way that I can it do it using the win api?

Comment: There's the device access API. Code sample here [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Custom-device-access-sample-43bde679)